# Git randomly resets to initial commit

Tags: git

4 times now in the past few days I've performed a seemingly innocuous git command (git push or git diff), and then git suddenly seems to be pointing to the project initial commit. The repository is 10+ years old with hundreds of thousands of commits.

```
$ git status
=> On branch my-current-branch-name

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

new file:   .Vagrantfile.example
new file:   .floo
new file:   .flooignore
new file:   .gitignore
new file:   .gitmodules
new file:   .rubocop.yml
... thousands of more files (all new to git) ...

$ git stash list
=> 
$ git tag
=> 
$ git branch
=> * my-current-branch-name
$ git checkout origin/master
=> error: pathspec 'origin/master' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

So I've been running `git reset --soft` to a recent SHA on that same branch, which at least gets me back to where I was on that branch. I have to then fetch the repository and re-checkout branches.

The only thing I can think of that may relate to this issue is that a few days ago, I got:

```
error: The last gc run reported the following. Please correct the root cause and remove .git/gc.log.
Automatic cleanup will not be performed until the file is removed.
warning: There are too many unreachable loose objects; run 'git prune' to remove them.
```

So I ran `git prune` and `rm .git/gc.log`. The next day was when I first had the initial commit issue. I have noticed that `.git/gc.log` has not been recreated, though `.git/gc.log.lock` still exists.

Any suggestions of what I might try next time this happens?

Comment: Are you sure the file permissions for `.git` folder are right?

Comment: @zed It looks right to me: `drwxr-xr-x  8 dev dev  4096 Feb  3 16:08 .git` (current user is dev)

Comment: Is your Git repository purely local to your machine? If you try to work in, e.g., a dropbox folder, or a network drive, or anything else that uses stuff automatically sent and received over a network, this can result in these kinds of issues.

Comment: What does `git log origin/master` return?  Does it return just the initial commit?

Comment: @torek good question. It is purely local.

Comment: @jbu I'll check next time it happens, but won't it produce `error: pathspec 'origin/master' did not match any file(s) known to git.` just as it did when I ran  `git checkout origin/master`?

Comment: It's definitely peculiar. You could run `git fsck` just to see if that thinks everything is OK, but it looks as though the last time this happened, your references (.git/packed-refs, probably) and index were damaged/removed. It might also be worth verifying your hardware itself, i.e., that there is no bad RAM, failing power supply, S.M.A.R.T. errors from the drive, etc.

Comment: @jbu happened again this morning `git log origin/master` does indeed show the current log of commits. They why would I need to `git fetch`?

Comment: A terminal history output would be nice so we can see what commands you did leading up to the problem